# Multiple annotations found at this line: jsp html

Tags: jsp

Am getting this error on this code...
Duplicate local variable value
    - Duplicate local variable 
     displayValue
    - Missing end tag for 
     "form:option"

```
<td>Year</td>
<td><form:select path="p1q5">
<form:option value=''>
   <form:option value="2014" label="2014"/>
   <form:option value="2015" label="2015"/>
   </form:select></td>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 1st `form:option`, you just forgot the end tag. This should work :

```
<form:option value=''/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed tag for first option, `<form:option value=''>`.